# Open pre-existing page and change parts of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using javascript to open the species_county file in a new window/tab and then jquery to change the contents of an h1 tag with id speciesTitle.

**open_event_test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new window called "MsgWindow" with some text.    </p>

<button onclick="myFunction('Yada')">Yada</button>

<script>
function myFunction(species) 
{
      console.log(species);
      var myWindow = window.open("species_county.html", species);
      myWindow.document.getElementById("speciesTitle").html(species);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**species_county.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="speciesTitle">Species in County</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I get error saying the element I'm grabbing has value null. I need to replace only some content. Document.write does not work because it will not open the species_county file, it will create an entirely new page.

Comment: So what is it that you want? The top of your question contradicts the bottom, or am i reading this wrong?

Comment: I am not too sure on what it is you are asking but if you are opening a new page you probably will want to do it in PHP or at least store a session variable.

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting? You may have cross-origin issues trying to alter the window of another frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possible issues with your script.

***1) Elements Do Not Have html Method***

As mentioned by **beercohol**, there is no such method as `html()` on an [HTML Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). `html()` is a jQuery method, which is a property of a jQuery Object. In order to use this, you need to either use jQuery to select the element, or use JavaScript's native `innerHTML` property.

```
myWindow.document.getElementById("speciesTitle").innerHTML = species;

// or

$(myWindow.document).find('#speciesTitle').html(species);
```

***2) The Window/Frame's DOM Has Not Loaded***

There's a high chance that, by the time you've run the code to change the `speciesTitle` element, the window that you've opened has not yet finished loading its DOM. This would result in an error along the lines of:

> TypeError: myWindow.document.getElementById(...) is null

You'll need to somehow make sure that you don't run the HTML-altering code until the DOM of the new window has finished loading. Traditionally, this is a job for jQuery, but here's a quick (non-cross-browser-friendly) pure JavaScript example within your `myFunction` method:

```
function myFunction (species) {
  var myWindow = window.open("species_county.html", species);
  myWindow.onload = function() {
    // DOM has loaded
    this.document.getElementById("speciesTitle").innerHTML = species;
  }
}
```

***3) Same Origin Policy***

For security reasons, most browsers won't let you make adjustments to a window of another frame unless both frames come from the same origin. If you're working locally, the chances are you're not using a domain name or an IP address which match. Chrome doesn't let you make these communications over the filesystem (not by default anyway), but I have had some success with Firefox waiving Same Origin Policy between files locally on the file system. Either way, this won't work on a legitimate browser if you are attempting to communicate with a frame from a completely different domain.

For more information, see the [window.open() FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#FAQ) on the MDN website. Note the part about cross-domain:

> A script loaded in a window (or frame) from a distinct origin (domain
>   name) cannot get nor set properties of another window (or frame) or
>   the properties of any of its HTML objects coming from another distinct
>   origin (domain name).

***4) Popup Blockers***

It's also likely that you may run into trouble with various browser implementations of popup blockers. These will outright refuse to open the new frame, resulting in a `null` window object. You will first need to 'allow' your page to open a window through some configuration in the browser (usually a popup-blocker icon makes itself apparent).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is that `html()` is not a method of the `Element` object returned by `getElementById()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

The property you're looking for is `innerHTML` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Try this for your script:

```
<script>
function myFunction(species)  {
      console.log(species);
      var myWindow = window.open("species_county.html", species);
      myWindow.document.getElementById("speciesTitle").innerHTML = species;
}
</script>
```

`html()` is a jQuery function, so I suspect that's where you're getting confused. You don't really need jQuery just for this however, although you are including it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify an element on a different page, and that's not possible with JavaScript in the way you're handling it.

One way to achieve your goal is to pass a $_GET parameter and use JavaScript on the newly loaded page to change the element.

Change this:

```
var myWindow = window.open("species_county.html", species);
myWindow.document.getElementById("speciesTitle").html(species);
```

To this:

```
var url = "species_county.html?species=" + encodeURIComponent(species);
window.open(url);
```

And then in species_county.html, look for the species parameter and change the title.

```
var mySpecies = location.search.split('species=')[1];
if(mySpecies !== undefined) {
   document.getElementById("speciesTitle").innerHTML=mySpecies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, shennan's 3rd idea was right, so I had to end up solving it like this:
**open_event_test**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new window called "MsgWindow" with some text.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('Bombus balteatus')"><em>Bombus balteatus</em> Dahlbom</button>
<button onClick="myFunction('Bombus auricomus')"><em>Bombus auricomus</em> (Robertson)</button>

<script>
function myFunction(species) 
{
     var newhtml = '<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><html><title>'+species+'</title></head><body><h1><em>'+species+'</em> in County</h1></body></html>';

     var newWindow = window.open(species, '_blank');
     newWindow.document.write(newhtml);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```